# How to use Rinkeby to display web3 front end of smart contract other than localhost

Tags: web3js, rinkeby, openzeppelin-contracts

Is there some functionality with Rinkeby to display my smart contract on something other than localhost so that other members of my team can access the frontend?  Will I have to make my own server or is there a better way to do it?

I have tried looking into this and the answer seems really hard to find.  I find plenty of solutions for people to display their projects locally but I cant find a solution for something other than localhost with rinkeby

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want others to interact with your Smart Contract on Rinkeby, they can just go to: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ and enter the contract address.

Make sure your contract is verified!

**Note:** This won't display your UI but it will give a decent UI for contract interactions. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Admittedly, this is the quickest and easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

the answer was github react pages